# CSS - Make mouse pointer disappear after some seconds

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

The objective is to hide my mouse pointer after some time when i mouse over a video, like youtube for example, for that i need to use css.

this is my animation right now.

```
  #container{
   &:hover{
     cursor: pointer;
    .video-controls-bar{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .bottom {
      margin-bottom: 44px;
    }
   }
  }
```

this is for my control bar and my div bottom appear when i mouse over, but now i need to hide the mouse after some seconds. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a keyframe animation such as this:

```
button:hover {
  animation: hideMouse 4s;

}

@keyframes hideMouse {
  0% {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  99% {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  100% {
    cursor: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: if he want to hide it should none not default

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks for the help man, the only problem is that the mouse dont disappear, even whit the none...weird

Comment: @HugoSeleiro because you need to add forwards to the animation .. by the way if the solution is not good wait before accepting ;)

Comment: @HugoSeleiro all what you need is this : https://jsfiddle.net/0pu57xy3/

Comment: @TemaniAfif, It work, now i need to make it appear when i move the mouse :D, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
keyframe animation with standard and safari browser

button:hover{
    -webkit-animation: hideMouse 5s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: hideMouse 5s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes hideMouse {
    0% {cursor: pointer;}
    99.5%  {cursor: pointer;}
    100% { cursor: none;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes hideMouse {
    0% {cursor: pointer;}
    99.5%  {cursor: pointer;}
    100% { cursor: none;}
}
```